# C# Inheritance of same class twice

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say I've such code

```
public class Holded
{
    protected internal int holdedID = 0;
}

public class Inventory : Holded
{
    public Inventory() { }

    public void changeHoldedID()
    {
        this.holdedID = 100;
    }
}

public class Equipment : Holded
{
    public Equipment() { }

    public void writeHoldedID()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Holded ID is: {0}!", this.holdedID);
    }
}

public class Cargo : Holded
{
    public Cargo() { }
}
```

If I'd call changeHoldedID and then writeHoldedID, console will still output a string like "Holded ID is: 0!". Now what I want to achieve is to have same base class (Holded) in both of classes. So if I'd change holdedID from Inventory, Equipment's writeHoldedID function would output "Holded ID is: 100!". Thanks and regards!

@Edit: More detailed: I have a game. Each person is a character, that owns Equipment, Inventory and Cargo class. Each class contains about 20 slots for "items". Now the thing is, that if you try to move an item, for ex. from inventory, to equipment, and there's such index of item, then the item is "swapped" - goes holded, and now I may throw such holded item into Equipment, Inventory or Cargo. That's why I'm in need to share such class between Eq/Inv/Cargo.

Comment: Sounds like you just want `Holded` to implement 2 different interfaces, perhaps that's a better way to go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Dictionary to store the person and their HoldedId might work

```
public class Holded
{
    protected internal static Dictionary<string, int> _personHoldedIDs;
    internal string _person;

    public Holded(string person)
    {
        _person = person;

        if (_personHoldedIDs == null)
            _personHoldedIDs = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        if (!_personHoldedIDs.ContainsKey(_person))
            _personHoldedIDs.Add(_person, 0);
    }
}

public class Inventory : Holded
{
    public Inventory(string person) : base(person) { }

    public void changeHoldedID()
    {
        _personHoldedIDs[_person] = 100;
    }
}

public class Equipment : Holded
{
    public Equipment(string person) : base(person) { }

    public void writeHoldedID()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Holded ID is: {0}!", _personHoldedIDs[_person]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With this inheritance structure, what you are asking is 99.9% impossible.

When you create an `Inventory` object, you are also creating a `Holded` object with its own `holdedID` member. When you create an `Equipment` object, you get a **new** `Holded` object as well, with **no relation** to the old one. Thus, changes to one objects member won't affect the other, *and you want it this way*.

*To be clear, you don't get a seperate `Holded` object when creating a derived class, but it can be helpful to think of it in the way I described it.

I don't know why you want to do what you are asking, but its a pretty good bet you need to rework your understanding of inheritance, objects, and polymorphsim.

Now, I said this was 99.9% impossible. You *can* mark the base class member `static` which shares it among *all* instances of `Holded` (and derived classes), making your code possible. **However, there is almost no chance you actually want to do this**. `static` should only be used when you understand object-oriented design and the consequences of using it.

Comment: The problem, is that I need one Inventory & Equipment class for each person (I have about 100 persons). So in my meaning - it can't be static. Tho, I need implementation of Holded for every Inventory / Equipment, because the Holded must be shared between those classes - it's simplier for me to keep it this way. Now, do you see any other way, to get out of this situation, beside initializing classes with 'Holded' class as argument, and storing such class in a variable & then implementing same functions related to Holded for both Inventory / Equipment? Thanks, and regards.

Comment: @mexikanoZ The answer to that can only be known with a little more detail. For instance, what is "holdedId"? Why does it need to be shared between instances, and why does one class set it and the other class return it???

Comment: More detailed: I have a game. Each person is a character, that owns Equipment, Inventory and Cargo class. Each class contains about 20 slots for "items". Now the thing is, that if you try to move an item, for ex. from inventory, to equipment, and there's such index of item, then the item is "swapped" - goes holded, and now I may throw such holded item into Equipment, Inventory or Cargo. That's why I'm in need to share such class between Eq/Inv/Cargo.

Comment: @mexikanoZ Sounds like `Equiptment` and `Inventory` should just have a `List<Item>` with exposed `Add` and `Remove` methods. Then when you swap them, you just call the appropriate methods. You may not even need an inheritance relationship here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered, instead of *"is a"* inheritance type relationship a *"contains a"* relationship?

You could do something along the following lines:

```
public interface IHolded
{
     Bar Foo();
}

public class Holded: IHolded { ... }
```

And now you have two options in how you want to implent `Equipment` and `Inventory`:

1. Directly exposing `holded` throgh a readonly property:

   ```
    public class Inventory
    {
        public Inventory(IHolded holded) { ... }
        public IHolded Holded { get; }
    }
   ```
2. Having them implement the `IHolded` interface and delegating
   implementation to `holded`.

   ```
   public Equipment
   {
        private readonly IHolded holded;

        public Equipment(IHolded holded) { this.holded = holded; }

        public Bar Foo() { return holded.Foo() };
   }
   ```

This way you are injecting  a `Holded` object when creating `Equipment` and `Inventory` instances ensuring a consistent state in both instances.